# Django- getting a list of foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    child = models.ForeignKey("ChildModel")

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now, given some filter on ParentModels, I want to retrieve a list of all children models.  I have tried:

```
children = ParentModel.objects.filter(name__startswith='A').values_list('child', flat=True)
```

However this returns a list of ChildModel ids, rather than the full objects.  Is there a queryset function that will accomplish what I am trying to do or do I need to write an additional filter query using the returned ids?  I.e.- instead of:

```
children => [51L, 53L, 54L]
```

I want:

```
children => [<ChildModel: ChildModel Object>, <ChildModel: ChildModel Object>, <ChildModel: ChildModel Object>]
```

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "some filter on ParentModels"? What kind of filter?

Comment: Sure, it could be something like `ParentModel.objects.filter(name__startswith='A')` to retrieve all parents whose name starts with 'A' (and then grab all child models of those parents)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `__in`:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__in=Parent.objects.filter(name__startswith='A'))
```

(Note, your naming is a bit odd here: usually the child is the one with the foreign key, since it assumes that a parent can have multiple children.)

Comment: Yes, I realize my naming was a bit backwards.  Was trying to take a much more complex set of foreign key relations and simplify it to the root of the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: this will not preserve the order of the inner queryset!

Answer (score 6):

I think you may want to refactor your models to be something like:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
```

Then you can just do the following to receive a queryset list of `ChildModel`:

```
ParentModel.childmodel_set.all()
```

This would be interpreted as "each ParentModel can have many ChildModel's."

Answer (score 5):

This one was an active issue on the Django site:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8144

You have two options:

1. Write your own queryset subclass
2. Add another filter to get the object of your retreived ids

I know how to implement option 2, so here is my approach:

Option #2:

```
children_ids = ParentModel.objects.filter(name__startswith='A').values_list('child', flat=True)
children = ChildModel.objects.filter(pk__in=children_ids)
```