# Django Filtering Foreign Key Item

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I make simple daily cleaning check app. the app is simple, the user observe certain areas and check whether the areas are clean or not. after all checking the user needs to report to authorities that will approve his daily cleaning works. The authorities here are maker, checker and signer. cln_daily model here represent daily cleaning works that will have maker, checker and signer from User model.

I have app called **user** that has costumized **User** model in **model.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(_('phone number'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

this User has ManyToMany Relationship with Group queryset: **maker, checker, signer**

```
>>> print(Group.objects.all()) 
<QuerySet [<Group: maker>, <Group: checker>, <Group: signer>]>
```

In other app called **cleaning** I have **cln_daily** model that has foreignkey relationship with that **User** model **based on their group**.

```
class cln_daily(models.Model):
   .
   .
   user_maker = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name="Maker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="makerSignature", blank=True, null=True,)
   user_checker = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Checker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="checkerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
   user_signer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Signer's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
```

So what I mean is **user_maker** queryset has users that only belong to group **maker**. **user_checker** has users that only belong to group **checker** and **user_signer** queryset has users that only belong to group **signer**.
How to express filtered User model in that **model.py**?

Comment: I think these information is not enough to answer/solve your question, would you please perform more information about it? i mean what do you want to do generally?

Comment: I want to filter User based on their group and use them in foreign key. Ex: I filter User in maker group, and relate them to user_maker. So in user_maker I only have User that has group maker. @EbrahimKarimi

Comment: look when i say i need more information, i mean the whole project because i've read your question and simply didn't get what do you want to accomplish. E.x: what are thoes makers? do they make something?(yeah they make Cars object) i want all the users they make cars but i don't know how to filter it! thats a question

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi I make simple **daily cleaning check** app. the app is simple, the user observe certain areas and check whether the areas are clean or not. after all checking the user needs to report to authorities that will approve his daily cleaning works. So the authorities here are **maker, checker and signer**. **cln_daily** model here represent daily cleaning works that will have maker, checker and signer from **User** model.

Comment: edit your question for clarification

Comment: so every time a row inserted into  `cln_daily` model, a report will be submitted which three times by three people(maybe the same) needs to be approved, right?

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi yes. **user_maker** will only retrieve  list of **maker** and choose one of them. any idea i can do it in model.py?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something about your problem, you wanna join tables in a simple way ,right? , I recommend to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062541/7337499) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587580/7337499)

and fix these model relationship in this way because by time it would be a problem:

```
class cln_daily(models.Model):
   .
   .
   user_maker = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name="Maker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="makerSignature", blank=True, null=True,)
                                  ^^^^
   user_checker = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Checker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="checkerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
                                   ^^^^^
   user_signer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Signer's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
                                   ^^^^
```

instead of using `User` in the `ForeignKeyField` it would be better to user `get_user_model()` or using this patter as str(cause you have to import it in your code first):

```
class cln_daily(models.Model):
   .
   .
   user_maker = models.ForeignKey('myapp.User',verbose_name="Maker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="makerSignature", blank=True, null=True,)
   user_checker = models.ForeignKey('myapp.User', verbose_name="Checker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="checkerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
   user_signer = models.ForeignKey('myapp.User', verbose_name="Signer's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signerSignature", blank=True, null=True)
```

because in time it would be migrations problem specually if you are new in django

Comment: thanks for your answer bro. I solved it on forms. it's tricky but it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

After long searched. I tricked it by solved it in forms

```
class MCSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = cln_daily
        fields = ("__all__")
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_maker'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='maker')
        self.fields['user_checker'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='checker')
        self.fields['user_signer'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='signer')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have better answer instead of tricking them in forms. using **limit_choices_to** in FKField

```
User = get_user_model()
class cln_daily(models.Model):
   .
   .
   user_maker = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name="Maker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="makerSignature", blank=True, null=True,limit_choices_to={'groups__name':'maker'})
   user_checker = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Checker's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="checkerSignature", blank=True, null=True,limit_choices_to={'groups__name':'checker'})
   user_signer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Signer's Signature",on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signerSignature", blank=True, null=True,limit_choices_to={'groups__name':'signer'})
```